# jQuery label 'for' attribute selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I am using Remy Sharp's [labelover plugin for jQuery](http://remysharp.com/2007/03/19/a-few-more-jquery-plugins-crop-labelover-and-pluck/) and I would like to exclude a label with the attribute `for` and value `nature`.

Here's an example of the code working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form.default label').labelOver('over');
});
```

and what I'm trying to do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form.default label').not($('label').attr('for','nature')).labelOver('over');
});
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? Feels like I'm pretty close to what I need to do.

Answer (score 27):

`attr` is not a selector, it's a function that gets the attribute value with attribute name as the 1st argument, or sets it with a new value if one is passed as a 2ng argument.

Also, you excluded labels after selecting them with your `not` call, because the selector `label` matched all labels, and `attr` as I said did not filter that.

To select based on attribute, use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form.default label[for!='nature']").labelOver('over');
});
```

As you may have guessed, the `[attribute='value']` is the selector for an attribute "equal" to some value, and `[attribute!='value']` is the "not equal" version of it.

For reference see:
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/

For reference on all selectors:
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

This is also referenced at my [JavaScript & Web Dev Newsletter site](http://gurustop.net).

Answer (score 3):

`.attr('for', 'nature')` is setting the value for the `for` attribute to `nature`

To filter by attributes, use `[attribute="value"]`:

```
$('form.default label').not('[for="nature"]').labelOver('over')
```

Answer (score 2):

working code: http://jsfiddle.net/3nQbr/1/

```
$('label').not('[for="nature"]').labelOver('over');
```